# Change a string to datetime field in client side

Tags: jquery, client-side

i have a string like  "Thu May 30 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)  ", and i need to change it to this format " 06/10/2013 03:16:55 PM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a date formatting plugin such as http://www.datejs.com/. (Looks like you'll have to get rid of the time zone name in parentheses yourself.)

Using that library, you can do this:

```
var input = "Thu May 30 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
input = input.replace(/\(.+\)/,''); // Get rid of the stuff in parentheses
Date.parse(input).toString("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"); //"05/30/2013 02:42:00 AM"
```